# Mysql add foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint on my schema `devair` from field `user_id` of table `bluePrints` to the PK `id` of table `users` but I get an error:

> ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Here are my table definitions:

**users**:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**bluePrints**:

```
CREATE TABLE `bluePrints` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bluePrintName` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And the offending `alter table` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `devair`.`bluePrints` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `bp_u`
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES `devair`.`users` (id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: What is with the `devair` there? Is it a table, or what?

Comment: can you give us the definition of your 'devair' table? if not... maybe that's your problem...

Comment: devair is the db name

Comment: clarified the question, some restructuring to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer would be that you need to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bp_id FOREIGN KEY (columnFromTable1) REFERENCES table2(columnReferencedFromTable2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that imply many users to one blueprint. It should be many-blueprints to one users

Comment: @MrLMrK, updated. It depends what YOU want. You actually add a foreign key like that, no  big deal. You say what column you have in table1 that needs to be the foreign key. Then you say what table is referenced and what column from that table.

Comment: @MrLMrK if the answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I see now the intuitive grey checkmark can turn green. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MrLMrK, my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the 'unsigned' in the bluePrints table. Once it's unsigned, then it works.

Now i have to figure out how to get laravel to use unsigned.

Comment: Well, after your `->interger()` just add `->unsigned()` easy as could be!